# odbc_exec taking a long time to execute a simple query

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc

I have been updating a php script to use an .mdb Access 2010 database, and I have been finding that the odbc_exec command is taking a really long time to execute. The SQL queries I am running are:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS fd FROM myTable WHERE ID > 3572 AND ( [field2] LIKE '%TEXT%')
SELECT MAX(ID) AS fd FROM myTable WHERE ID < 3572 AND ( [field2] LIKE '%TEXT%')
SELECT COUNT(*) AS fd FROM myTable WHERE ID <= 3572 AND ( [field2] LIKE '%TEXT%')
SELECT COUNT(*) AS fd FROM myTable WHERE ( [field2] LIKE '%TEXT%')
```

They are for a search result paging system which I am updating.
My php code is something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT MIN(ID) AS fd FROM myTable WHERE ID > 3572 AND ( [field2] LIKE '%TEXT%')"

$sqlconn = odbc_connect("my_data_source","","",SQL_CURSOR_FORWARD_ONLY);
$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);
$data = odbc_fetch_array($result);
odbc_free_result($result);
// more code using $data
```

When I run my code, I find that it takes a few minutes to run, which is far too long. By commenting out everything after it, I have tracked down the culprit to the `$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);` line. I am fairly new to php and odbc connections, and so far I haven't been able to find a reason why it takes so long. Running the query directly on the database is almost instantaneous.

`myTable` is a single table within the database that has about 60,000 records and 25 columns of data. It does not have a primary key field or any indexes that I know of, though adding a primary key does not seem to affect the run time by any siginificant amount.

Some things I have already tried include increasing the ODBC Data Source buffer size from 2048 to 4096, adding a primary key on the ID field in the database, and using the `SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC` cursor option instead of the `SQL_CURSOR_FORWARD_ONLY` option.

**Update**
I don't know if this is relevant, but I noticed something odd when the query was running from the php file. The .mdb database is in a folder with several other .mdb databases, and when the query was running, every one of them was locked (had the accompanying .ldb file). It also caused Apache to run very slowly.

I don't know what other relevant information to post, so if there is something I am missing please let me know.

Comment: Like '%...' is probably going to be slow as it will not use indexes.

Comment: Is the .mdb file on a local drive of the machine where the PHP script is executing?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, this is all currently running on my local machine.

Comment: re: multiple .ldb files - Do all of the .ldb files go away when the PHP script finishes?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes they do

Comment: @Remou You are probably right that the LIKE statement is slowing it down. Unfortunately these queries are for a search engine and I don't know a better way to search a field for the indicated TEXT. This example is only using one LIKE statement, but if other fields are also searched on then I will have to add more LIKE statements. After some research it seems that Access is not the best for these situations, though I would prefer to stay with it if possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible to get an sargable subset / subtable and apply Like to that?

Comment: @Remou I don't believe I can get one in this situation, but it was a good suggestion. I seem to have stumbled across a solution however. I removed a bunch of unnecessary tables from my database to reduce its size, and then I ran the "Compact and Repair" tool on the database. I don't fully understand what is involved in that process other than getting a smaller database, but now my queries are running great, only taking a second or two for the larger result sets. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: You might like to decompile as well, it may not help, but it will not hurt. http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/decompile.htm and / or http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Decompile Make sure you back up before decompile. You might like to look at http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=95&t=9011&sid=5141c63e74fac98facee5b2fb630c6f4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the `LIKE '%TEXT%'` conditions are the bottleneck, forcing a table scan for each query. If those `LIKE` conditions are always going to be the same for each batch of four queries (i.e., to get four values for the same subset of records) then using a temporary table would help a lot.

For a test table with 60,000 records, the following code takes around 10 or 11 seconds to run on my oldest and creakiest test box:

```php
$sql = "SELECT MIN(ID) AS fd FROM myTable WHERE ID > 3572 AND ( [field2] LIKE '%TEXT%')";
$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);
$data = odbc_fetch_array($result);
odbc_free_result($result);
$v1 = $data['fd'];

$sql = "SELECT MAX(ID) AS fd FROM myTable WHERE ID < 3572 AND ( [field2] LIKE '%TEXT%')";
$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);
$data = odbc_fetch_array($result);
odbc_free_result($result);
$v2 = $data['fd'];

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS fd FROM myTable WHERE ID <= 3572 AND ( [field2] LIKE '%TEXT%')";
$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);
$data = odbc_fetch_array($result);
odbc_free_result($result);
$v3 = $data['fd'];

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS fd FROM myTable WHERE ( [field2] LIKE '%TEXT%')";
$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);
$data = odbc_fetch_array($result);
odbc_free_result($result);
$v4 = $data['fd'];
```

However, the following code completes in just 1 or 2 seconds on the same machine:

```php
$tempTableName = uniqid();

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tempTableName (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)";
$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);
$sql = 
        "INSERT INTO $tempTableName (ID) " .
        "SELECT ID FROM myTable WHERE ( [field2] LIKE '%TEXT%')";
$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);

$sql = "SELECT MIN(ID) AS fd FROM $tempTableName WHERE ID > 3572";
$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);
$data = odbc_fetch_array($result);
odbc_free_result($result);
$v1 = $data['fd'];

$sql = "SELECT MAX(ID) AS fd FROM $tempTableName WHERE ID < 3572";
$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);
$data = odbc_fetch_array($result);
odbc_free_result($result);
$v2 = $data['fd'];

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS fd FROM $tempTableName WHERE ID <= 3572";
$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);
$data = odbc_fetch_array($result);
odbc_free_result($result);
$v3 = $data['fd'];

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS fd FROM $tempTableName";
$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);
$data = odbc_fetch_array($result);
odbc_free_result($result);
$v4 = $data['fd'];

$sql = "DROP TABLE $tempTableName";
$result = odbc_exec($sqlconn, $sql);
```